# Select text in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I have an `input` element and it has text inside it by using ng-model, then I'm trying to select all text by creating custom detective:

```
.directive('selectText', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            elem.bind('focus', function() {
                $(elem).select();
            });
            scope.$watch("edit",function(newValue,oldValue) {
                $(elem).select();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

It works well, but I don't want it's text to be also selected when user `foucusout` from the control and `focusin` again. It should just select text only once (not on second focus).
Also how can I remove focus from element when all text is selected?

Comment: Do you want focousout immediately after selecting all text ? OR something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable that will hold boolean value if element is selected and select element only if it's not already selected. Like this:

```
.directive('selectText', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var selected = false;
            elem.bind('focus', function() {
                if (!selected) {
                    $(elem).select();
                    selected = true;
                }
            });
            scope.$watch("edit",function(newValue,oldValue) {
                $(elem).select();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: There are  no events like 'loaded', 'displayed', etc...?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Ctrl3($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'My relevant title';
}

angular.module('scopePropertiesModule', [])
  .directive('selectText', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        var counter = 0;
        elem.bind('focus', function() {
          console.log(counter)

          if (counter < 1) {
            $(elem).select();
            /*setTimeout(function() {
              $(elem).blur();
            }, 1000);*/
            
            counter++;
          }
        });
        scope.$watch("edit", function(newValue, oldValue) {
          $(elem).select();
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="scopePropertiesModule">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
    <input select-text ng-model="title">
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this.